# Javascript if statement set a time on the condition

Tags: javascript

I have an if statement with the condition that if numberOfFingers == 5 then the counter will increase by 1, I want the counter to increase by 1 only if the duration of numberOfFingers is 5 seconds. (this is with the leap motion) Is this possible?

```
    if (numberOfFingers == 5) {
        var start = parseInt(document.getElementById('count').innerHTML);
        var end = start+1;
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = end;
       }
```

Comment: Uhm, what? Duration of what exactly?

Comment: do you mean that  expression (numberOfFigers==5) stays true for 5 second?

Comment: @lombausch yes, sorry my write up was a bit unclear!

Comment: @adeneo apologies for being unclear. 5 seconds as in the duration of time the user hovers 5 fingers over the leap motion controller. Once they have hovered 5 fingers for 5 seconds then I want the count to go up by +1. I'm just not sure how i set up a condition for time.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at "setTimeout" and try something like this:

```
if(numberOfFingers == 5) { 
  setTimeout(function(){
    if(numberOfFingers == 5){ //5 fingers still after 5s
      var start = parseInt(document.getElementById('count').innerHTML);
      var end = start+1;
      document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = end;
    }
  }, 5*1000); //your 5s 
}
```

Comment: This will work, but will also catch situations where `numberOfFingers` changed to some other number within the 5 seconds and then changed back. A fully correct implementation would have to observe changes to `numberOfFingers` to make sure that it doesn't change over the 5 seconds. I don't know if this is important for this particular implementation.

Comment: @lombausch Thanks for your help, but this is not what i am after, I'm finding it quite difficult to explain! if the users numberOfFingers == 5 I want the count to display 1, if the user does it twice I want to display 2, if the user does it 3 times i want to display 3, and so forth, my issue is that with the leap motion when a user is hovering 5 fingers they are doing so with a duration of 1-5seconds this means that count is continuously being executed so when the user removes all fingers its left with a count of around 60. I'm wondering if there is a way to curtail this? thanks again!

Comment: I don't understand this part: "with the leap motion when a user is hovering 5 fingers they are doing so with a duration of 1-5seconds this means that count is continuously being executed so when the user removes all fingers its left with a count of around 60" I have no idea what are you after. :)

Comment: @lombausch haha! erm I'm after the count to just increase by 1 and then stop after the condition is met.. The count continues to increase because the users hand is normally over the controller for a few seconds. Is there a way to set a time inside the condition? e.g numberOfFingers == 5 and duration equal to 5 seconds, then the code will execute..  do you have a leap motion controller?